# Javascript Code Modification ... Simple Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement this simple jQuery Exit LightBox on my website...
(http://www.tonylea.com/2011/creating-a-jquery-exit-popup/)

The pop-up is very clever and simple, however it only works when a visitor is at the very top of the page. If the visitor is scrolled down, it wont work. One guy suggested the following fix to the PHP to solve this issue, but it keeps throwing a syntax error when I edit it in Dreamweaver.

Anyone notice where the error is or possible fix?  Thank you guys!

```
var oldPosition = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth / 2 – $('#exitpopup').width() / 2));
        $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight / 2 – $('#exitpopup').height() / 2));

        var position = e.pageY – $(window).scrollTop();

        if(position < 10) {
            if(oldPosition != -1) {
                if(position < oldPosition) {
                    // Show the exit popup
                    $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
                    $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
                }
                oldPosition = position;
            } else {
                oldPosition = position;
            }
        }
        $('#divData').html(oldPosition + " : " + position);
    });

    $('#exitpopup_bg').click(function() {
        $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
        $('#exitpopup').slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI: That's not PHP, it's Javascript; you may want to retag the question

Comment: instead of depending on dreamweaver to spot your javascript errors, cant you check your firebug console for the actual error?

Comment: Change your tag to javascript and jquery instead of php

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. I'm not a genius with this, that's why I'm having problems haha. I will re-tag.   Thank you.

Comment: I think you were confused with `$` sign.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with firebug, I never really get in depth with the codes, but usually end up fumbling through to modify to suit my needs.   Just can't figure this one out.  Haha, thanks again.

Comment: if you use chrome, its just simple as open up your webpage in chrome and press F12 to open the inspector and take the console tab. It will tell you where your code breaks.

Comment: OT: For me that is one site that I would never, *ever* visit again. Also, it's fairly buggy and unreliable.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh, The error that I got said "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL ....  any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: @IngoBürk - Why do you say that?  I just came across it when searching for a exit popup lightbox.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan - Was that sarcasm? haha... I apologize, I'm somewhat of a novice when it comes to this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user3089680: click on the filename along right side of that error in console. It will take you to the exact line.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Thank you.  I think it is showing me the line, but I am not sure.  Would you mind seeing if you could find it? ... here is my file link: http://mudchallenger.com/exitpopup.php 

Forgive me if this is not possible, I'm new here.

Comment: @user3089680 I say it because I think that a) implementing this is an anti-pattern, it decreases user experience and it's simply annoying; and b) because it's buggy. I can discuss this further in an off-topic answer, if you like (comments aren't a good format for this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in theses lines:

```
$('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth / 2 – $('#exitpopup').width() / 2));
$('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight / 2 – $('#exitpopup').height() / 2));
var position = e.pageY – $(window).scrollTop();
```

Replace `–` with minus `-` sign.

```
 $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth / 2 - $('#exitpopup').width() / 2));
 $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight / 2 - $('#exitpopup').height() / 2));
 var position = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
```